# How do i convert a 4 dimensional angle into a 4 dimensional vector?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a four dimensional physics simulation.

I want to be able to convert a four dimensional angle (Pitch, Yaw, Roll, ???) to a four dimensional vector (X, Y, Z, W).

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: your question is a bit vague, do you not know the mathematics behind this, have your tried to write some code already yourself? I would propose you give more details so we understand how we can help you.

Comment: 3D polar/spherical coordinates use 2 angles and a radius - wouldn't 4D polar coordinates use 3 angles and a radius, rather than 4 angles?

Comment: Obviously, you start by working out the correct formulas. That makes it a math question rather than a programming question. Are you familiar with [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)? You may find help on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Quaternion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn889176(v=vs.111).aspx): 
The constructor takes 4 Single.